# How does waiting & atomic clock help GCP spanner solve Linearizability and Serializability in distributed transaction?

Tags: database, concurrency, distributed-system, google-cloud-spanner

My understanding why distributed transaction need synchronized clock is the following

Assume NTP max drift is 250ms

```
true time = 100ms
node A local time = 100ms
node B local time = 0ms
```

the following transaction will run into conflicted sequenece

```
transactionA arrive nodeA at (true time 100ms, A time 100ms, B time 0ms)
transactionA commit by nodeA at (true time 110ms, A time 110ms, B time 10ms)
nodeB gets transactionA replicated at (true time 111ms, A time 111ms, B time 11ms) BUT with timestamp (110ms)
transactionB arrive nodeB at (true time 120ms, A time 120ms, B time 20ms)
transactionB is commit by nodeB at (true time 130ms, A time 130ms, B time 30ms)
```

now there is a conflict in transaction time between transactionA and transactionB

```
transactionA commit time = 110ms (local of A)
transactionB commit time = 30ms (local of B)
```

transaction A should be processed before transaction B , but because node B lag node A by 100ms transactionB is now considered to be processed before transactionA

Spanner have atomic clock that guarantees max time drift to be 7ms, and it waits this max uncertainty time of 7ms before commit. But how does that fundamentally solve the issue?

Imagine the following example

```
true time = 7ms
node A local time = 7ms
node B local time = 0ms



trxA arrive nodeA at (true time 7ms, A time 7s, B time 0ms)
trxA commit by nodeA at (true time 8ms, A time 8ms, B time 1ms)
trxB arrive nodeB at (true time 9ms, A time 9ms, B time 2ms)
trxB is commit by nodeB at (true time 10ms, A time 10ms, B time 3ms)
nodeA report trxA after waiting 7ms (true time 15ms, A time 15ms, B time 8ms)
nodeB report trxB after waiting 7ms (true time 17ms, A time 17ms, B time 10ms)
```

In this example 7ms wait doesn't solve the problem, trxB is still committed at 3ms (local nodeB time) trxA is committed at 8ms (local nodeA time)

The conflict of trxB committed before trxA still exist

What am i missing here?

Comment: Spanner's meticulous approach to time synchronization and conflict resolution allows it to deliver exceptional consistency guarantees in the demanding world of distributed databases. By mastering time, Spanner ensures that transactions execute in a predictable, orderly fashion, upholding data integrity and empowering applications to operate seamlessly across vast geographic distances.

Comment: Have you see https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/true-time-external-consistency and the papers linked from that page?